# Deleting Google Chrome address bar suggestion

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

When I type "sport" in Google Chrome's address bar, I get this:

[image]
But when I type "sport." I get this one:

[image]

I've deleted all history, of all time. But I still get "www.sport.ro" as a suggestion (green one). I've never visited this site (*on purpose*) as I don't speak Romanian.

I've tried <kbd>Fn+Shift+Del</kbd> or only <kbd>Shift+Del</kbd> while selecting the entry with the arrows but nothing happens as it seems to work (temporarily) only for entries with the magnifying glass icon in front.

How do I remove it from the suggestions?

Comment: Is your browser language correct? do you have the problem with this one case or more?

Comment: For almost everything I write there is a suggestion, but only big websites, e.g. yahoo, youtube, facebook, nike, etc.

Comment: Are you using the newest Chrome update ? I remember this was the case before, but know when you want to delete some suggestion like in your case you just hit Win+H and delete the site sport.ro. And the suggestion won't be made again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ever visited the site before, the following will help get rid of the suggestion.

- Download and install [SQLite Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) if you don't already have it.(the portableApps version will do.)
- Copy my instructions somewhere and close Chrome. (this won't work with chrome open.)
- Navigate to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` and open the `Shortcuts` file in the sqlite browser that you just downloaded
- Under the `Browse Data` tab, select `omno_box_shortcuts` from the `Table:` dropdown.
- Under the 'contents' column, in the `Filter` box, type `www.sport.ro` and delete the row the shows up below.

That should do it. Open Chrome and let me know how it goes